# How to modify a podman container image

Tags: containers, podman

I'm new to podman and I'm trying to modify an image, this image is used to set up a service. However I want to use that image to do something else. The first process launched is the service (with a `pid=1`).

How can I modify what is launched as the first command when I start my container (with : `podman run xxxx`) ?

I tried connecting to the container but I couldn't find anything that could launch that command. I guess I'm not understanding how containers really work.

Comment: You don't modify an image. You build a new image configured as you want. Typically there is a "Dockerfile" which describes the steps to build an image and you would change that and create a modiified image. You can run other processes (e.g. start a shell) in a running container, but the "main" process is typically hard-wired for any particular image.